# Sprint JPA: How to add a Many-to-One object into MySQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Using Java Spring JPA.

I have a One to Many class called Events, and a Many to One Class called Users.

How would I attempt to add a user to an event using a URL?
I can't seem to get it to work. I've already marked the annotations on my Event and User class. All my other queries seem to work. I also want to preserve the many to one relationship.

This is the exception it throws (ignore the two)

```
Error creating bean with name 'eventRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract int com.mthree.repositories.EventRepository.addUserByIdtwo(int,java.lang.String,int) but parameter 'Optional[userId]' not found in annotated query 'INSERT INTO USER u.userId, u.userName FROM Event e inner join e.users u ON e.eventId = u.eventId WHERE e.eventId=:eventId'!
```

EventRestController.java

```
@GetMapping("/adduser{userName}/{eventId}")
    public ModelAndView addUserById(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, @PathVariable("userName") String userName, @PathVariable("eventId") int eventId){

        int numDeleted = eventService.addUserById(userId, userName, eventId);

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

        if(numDeleted>0) {

        mv.setViewName("successfuledit");

        }
        else {
            mv.setViewName("failededit");
        }

        return mv;
    }
```

EventService.java

```
    public int addUserById(int userId, String userName, int eventId) {
        return eventRepository.addUserById(userId, userName, eventId);
    }
```

EventRepository.java

```
@Query("INSERT INTO USER u.userId, u.userName FROM Event e inner join e.users u ON e.eventId = u.eventId WHERE e.eventId=:eventId")
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    public int addUserById(@Param("userId") int userId, @Param("userName") String userName,@Param("eventId") int eventId);
```

Comment: Missing slash in url ? - @GetMapping("/adduser{userName}/{eventId}")  ?

Comment: nope my other queries work even without the /. I can't even compile

Comment: So if you can't compile, would you bother to share the compilers errorr message with us?

Comment: Where you use userId and userName in the query ? and your query run-in console ?